# Volume determined by 3 planes

Tags: geometry

Find the volume of rectangular box determined by the following 3 planes  with the equations:

$ax + by + cz = \pm A$
$dx + ey + fz = \pm B$
$gx + hy + iz = \pm C$

I tried to make the changes of variable: 
$X=ax+by+cz$
$Y=dx+ey+fz$
$Z=gx+hy+iz$

And now with Jacobian matrix If determinant is $0$ the volume is null and why can I find  the volume when:
$X=A,   X=-A$  are the first pair of parallel planes.
$Y=B,   Y=-B$  are the second pair of parallel planes.
$Z=C,   Z=-C$  are the third pair of parallel planes.

Comment: Plane? (instead of "plan")

Comment: Try using $LaTeX$ and a spell check. "variabile" just is not professional enough.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The box is almost never *rectangular* hence the answer below, which uses this hypothesis crucially, is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between  the parallel planes  $$ax+by+cz = (+ or -) A$$ is $$ D _1 = \frac {2|A|}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Similarly$$ D _2= \frac {2|B|}{\sqrt {d^2+e^2+f^2}}$$ and $$ D _3= \frac {2|C|}{\sqrt {g^2+h^2+i^2}}$$
Thus the volume of the box is $$ V =  \frac {2|A|}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}}\frac {2|B|}{\sqrt {d^2+e^2+f^2}}\frac {2|C|}{\sqrt{g^2+h^2+i^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks very much! I understood

Comment: @Petrisor Thanks for attention.